# Can I burn a token that already exists with no burnable functionality inside its smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, nft

Can I burn a token that already exists with no burnable functionality inside its smart contract? Can i create a new contract with a burn function and call the specific smart contract and token ID that I want to be burned? If possible, could you provide an example.

Below attached is the smart contract with no burn function

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFT_TOKEN is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;
    
    string public baseURI;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    uint256 public cost = 0.01 ether;
    uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
    uint256 public maxMintAmount = 20;
    bool public paused = false;
    
    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI
    )   ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        mint(msg.sender, 1);
            
    }
      
    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }
    
    // public
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(!paused);
        require(_mintAmount > 0);
        require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
        require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);
        
        if(msg.sender != owner()) {
            require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
        }
        
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
            _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
        }
          
    }
      
    function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
            
      {
        uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokenIds;
    }
    
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
      {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );
        
        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return 
          bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
            ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension))
            : "";
    }
      
    // only owner
    function  setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner() {
        cost = _newCost;
          
    }
      
    function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner() {
        maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
    }
      
    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner() {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }
      
    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension) public onlyOwner() {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }
      
    function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner() {
        paused = _state;
    }
      
    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner() {
        require(payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance));
    }

} ```
````

Comment: No you cannot. “Probably” The only thing you can do is making the owner do that token disapprove all and then send it to a dead address

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.